# Criar um link para um único usuário sem senha no banco de dados

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Atualmente eu tenho um BD de orçamentos, clientes e oficinas. Quando gero uma demanda de um cliente eu tenho que cotar nas oficinas o valor e depois escolher o melhor custo x benefício e passar para o cliente.

O que quero fazer é gerar um link para a oficina tipo www.meusite.com.br/orcamentos/$$@#@@#$2352525234. Este hash seria o ID do orçamento e ao entrar no link ele vai ter que digitar o CNPJ (este eu tenho no BD). Assim ele vai digitar os valores e condições e gravar. Eu vou receber uma notificação e passo para o cliente.

Estou desenvolvendo em Laravel e VueJS. Queria saber se isto é viável, não quero que as oficinas tenham sistema de login no site.

Deu para entender?

Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 0):

Vou fazer um exemplo com base no que eu entendi, e usando o padrão models e relationships através das models.

Controller em questão:

```
public function acao1 ($id_orcamento){
    return view('view.digitar.cpf');
}

public function acao2 ($cpf,$id_orcamento){
    try{
        $usuario = UsuarioModel::where('cpf', $cpf')->firstOrFail();
        $orcamento = OrcamentoModel::find($id_orcamento);
        return view('info.orcamento', compact('orcamento'));
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return view('usuario.nao.encontrado');
    }
}
```

Você poderia fazer algo do tipo. É claro que da pra estruturar melhor isso ai, mas como eu to fazendo um exemplo só pra te dar um norte, isso é um bom começo.

Você não precisa necessariamente usar o firstorfail dentro de um trycatch, pode simplesmente usar o first() depois um `if( isset($usuario) ){...} else {...}`

Comment: Beleza Matheus, já tenho um norte. Vou estudar direito o que me passou.